# Invite new users for my app using app notifications facebook

Tags: android, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, notifications

My app logs in via facebook and all friends of facebook user logged is listed to be invited to download my app. I want guests to be advised via facebook through a notification.
I've done the test via "Graph Api Explore" as follows:

> POST/{recipient_userid}/notifications? access_token = ... & template = John is inviting you to learn a new app. & href = ... "

but I noticed that the notification comes only to those who already have my application installed.

> {return: "(#200) Cannot send notifications to a user who has not installed the app"}

how do I send notifications for facebook users that still do not have my application installed?
thks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because notifications are not meant to be used to invite friends. They're used to notify your app users of events happening in the app (e.g. if their high score was beaten in a game for example).

If you want to let your user invite friends to also use the app, I'd suggest you use the Request & Invite features of the Facebook SDK:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/ios-sdk-games/requests/

That tutorial shows you how your user can select a list of friends to invite and then write a message that will accompany the invitation.

Comment: thank you! You saved my day! +1000 for you but my reputation is still low.